# Добавить кнопку В корзину WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно добавить кнопку "В корзину" на странице категории каталога. Облазил все файлы шаблона, подходящего не нашел. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию вывод кнопки в категории стоит на событие

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

Стилизация вывода находится в шаблоне woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php

```
global $product;

echo apply_filters(
    'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', // WPCS: XSS ok.
    sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
        esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
        isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
    $product,
    $args
);
```

Comment: Сделал как Вы написали, правда шаблон игнорирует php. Что можно сделать? 
https://sun9-21.userapi.com/H7eNt6x8crXw-kmPzALKlJG3sob_mf3c0rhVWw/nHsdK-W1LGo.jpg

Comment: нужно вставить между тегов <?php <!--код из ответа--> ?>